# How to animate a bike chain with a low poly chainring?

Tags: animation

I need help with animating my chain, the chain isn't able to stick with the chainring because its quite low poly(both the chain and chainring) as shown as in the pic and the gap is very obvious I can't animate the chainring rotating with it like this.

How will I rig this to remain like tensioned while the chainring is rotating?[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is create a mesh that looks like the chain, with only the necessary amount of edge loops, hook these edge loops to empties, make the ring rotate 1/7 of 360°, move the empties and keyframe them so that they follow the ring rotation. Make the empties rotate a bit on themselves so that the chain keeps an even thickness. You can now make the rotation cyclic to give the illusion that it rotates 360° and more. I haven't hooked the left part of the chain but it's the same process.

[image]